# passing a private class instance by reference into a "get" function of another class c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am working on a assignment for an OOPs c++ course. This assignment is dealing with using set/get functions and constructors/persecutors.

I have some code that will compile with VS professional 2015(windows) and run but will not compile on our linux lab(I need it to compile here so I can run a test bed to make sure I have no styling errors before turning in, also if it won't compile I'll get some points off)

So what code I am working on is creating four different classes.

Address, Product, Customer, Order ([**Code**](https://github.com/goytia54/assign5))

[**Customer**](https://github.com/goytia54/assign5/blob/master/customer.h) has a class private member variables that is an instance of Address. 
[**Order**](https://github.com/goytia54/assign5/blob/master/order.h) has two class private member variables, instance of Address and Customer.

As stated earlier the purpose of the assignment is to become more familiar with set/get functions.

My professor has made it clear that "get" functions should return a value not store a value(accessing private member variable).

For example in the class [**Address**](https://github.com/goytia54/assign5/blob/master/address.h) I use a "get" function to access the member variable street

```
string getStreet() { return street; }
```

Now when I need to make a get function for accessing a private member variable but that variable happens to be an instance of a class I wasn't sure what to do.

Sticking to my training I assumed that I would set something up like this([**Customer Class**](https://github.com/goytia54/assign5/blob/master/customer.h)).

```
Address getAddress() { return address; }
```

Likewise I setup a set function as follows

```
void setAddress(Address &address) 
{
        this->address.setStreet(address.getStreet());
        this->address.setCity(address.getCity());
        this->address.setState(address.getState());
        this->address.setZip(address.getZip());
}
```

Going one step deeper I then have a class called Order that has a private member variable instance of Customer. Now here is where I think I am getting into trouble.

I need to make a non-default constructor in which I pass in some instances where one of the instance is the customer class.

My constructor looks like so.

```
Order(Product &product, int quantity, Customer &customer)
    {
        this->product.setName(product.getName());
        this->product.setDescription(product.getDescription());
        this->product.setWeight(product.getWeight());
        this->product.setBasePrice(product.getBasePrice());
        this->quantity = quantity;
        this->customer.setName(customer.getName());
        this->customer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
    }
```

Now this process raises no errors of flags when running in VS professional 2015 however when I try to compile on the linux lab I get the error.

```
In file included from order.cpp:3:0:
order.h: In constructor ‘Order::Order(Product&, int, Customer&)’:
order.h:25:51: error: no matching function for call to‘Customer::setAddress(Address)’
    this->customer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
                                                   ^
order.h:25:51: note: candidate is:
In file included from order.h:7:0,
                 from order.cpp:3:
customer.h:32:8: note: void Customer::setAddress(Address&)
   void setAddress(Address &address)
        ^
customer.h:32:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Address’ to ‘Address&’
In file included from order.cpp:3:0:
order.h: In member function ‘void Order::setCustomer(Customer&)’:
order.h:39:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘Customer::setAddress(Address)’
    this->customer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
                                                   ^
order.h:39:51: note: candidate is:
In file included from order.h:7:0,
                 from order.cpp:3:
customer.h:32:8: note: void Customer::setAddress(Address&)
   void setAddress(Address &address)
        ^
customer.h:32:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Address’ to ‘Address&’
In file included from assign05.cpp:16:0:
order.h: In constructor ‘Order::Order(Product&, int, Customer&)’:
order.h:25:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘Customer::setAddress(Address)’
    this->customer.setAddress(customer.getAddress()); 
.........
```

where the rest of the error can be found [**here**](https://github.com/goytia54/assign5/blob/master/error.txt)

Now I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I feel that it has to do with how I am passing around the instance address and then trying to access it through the get function. Any insights on this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are not passing the address. `Address getAddress() { return address; }` returns a copy of the variable `address`. `Address& getAddress()` returns a reference to that internal variable, but now you are getting into hot water conceptually.

Comment: How would I then "cool the water" ?

Comment: And we are missing parts of the error. `customer.h:32:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Address’ to ‘Add ` this should be your clue

Comment: By not returning reference to internal variable. You either return a copyof or you act like a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: @Ceros sorry, the error didn't copy all the way it should say `customer.h:32:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Address’ to ‘Address&’`

Comment: Since `getAddress` returns a copy and `setAddress` accept a reference only, you need to store the returned copy of `getAddress` and then use that variable for the `setAddress`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: non-const lvalue reference to type `Address` cannot bind to a temporary of type `Address`.

Your `Customer::getAddress` returns a copy of address (temporary object/rvalue). But `Customer::setAddress` accepts lvalue (non-temporary object) reference.

The right solution is to make `Custom::setAddress` accept **const** lvalue reference. Since you are not modifing argument (and you **should not** do it) and **const** lvalue reference can bind to rvalue.

**Note:** Your code will not compile because of other error: you can't call non-const methods (getters in your case) on const object. Mark getters as const methods by adding `const` to end of declaration (like this: `string getState() const { return state; }`).

If you want to understand what is lvalue, rvalue exactly...
[What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues#3601661) and
http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Comment: +1 for the great answer @FoxCpp. People often forget (or don't even know) about lvalues and rvalues and what you are allowed to do with them per the standard.

Comment: So I added const to all my get functions and then passed all and I am not longer passing the class instances by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getAddress` returns a copy and `setAddress` accept a reference only, you need to store the returned copy of `getAddress` and then use that variable for the `setAddress`

```
auto wAddress = customer.getAddress();
this->customer.setAddress(wAddress);
```